# ArcGIS cached map service sometimes pausing

Tags: arcgis-server, map-service

I have published an ArcGIS service based on a MXD
I have generated the cached tiles on a shared NAS.
When I access the Map Service with the build in js admin viewer 
(http://SERVER/arcgis/rest/service/....)

The map display quickly but, every now and then no tiles are coming for maybe 5 seconds, and then they all come quickly.

Why could that be?
Any tip / ideas welcome?
How to diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using ArcGIS 10, try to clear your server cache [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/10/08/clearing-the-arcgis-services-directory-cache-the-easy-way/), if it makes problem.

and read this document **Map caching tips and best practices with ArcGIS Server 10** [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/03/22/map-caching-tips-and-best-practices-with-arcgis-server-10/), if you have missed anything when making ceched map....

[image: clearcache]

Answer (score 2):

On your web server, create a script that wakes your services up every 15 minutes or so.  Below is an example of a vbs file that the Windows Task Manager runs every 15 minutes:

```
'declare web app variable, set variable to be an IE application  
Dim webApp  
Set webApp= CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")  

'set visibility of the web app, can be set to false to run in the background  
webApp.Visible = true  

'declare a counter variable as integer, set it to zero  
Dim counter  
counter = 0  

'declare array to hold names of different services  
'simply increase the array by +1 and add a new entry for every new service that gets published  

dim services(6)   
services(0)="MapCache1/MapServer"  
services(1)="MapCache2/MapServer"  
services(2)="MapCache3/MapServer"  
services(3)="MapCache4/MapServer"  
services(4)="CompositeLocator/GeocodeServer"  
services(5)="Geometry/GeometryServer"  

dim map(4)  
map(0)="MapCache1/MapServer"  
map(1)="MapCache2/MapServer"  
map(2)="MapCache3/MapServer"  
map(3)="MapCache4/MapServer"  

'the following loop uses the REST API and the array to step through each service page  

Do while counter < 4  

    For Each x in services      
      webApp.Navigate "http://gisweb/ArcGIS/rest/services/"& x  
      wscript.sleep(2000)  
    Next

    For Each y in map  
      webApp.Navigate "http://gisweb/ArcGIS/rest/services/"& y & "?f=jsapi"  
      wscript.sleep(7000)  
    Next  

  counter = counter + 1  
Loop  

webApp.quit  
Set webApp = nothing
```